# Zend - Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_View_Exception: script '/.phtml'

Tags: zend-framework

Get the following error message on my app. The app is written with the Zend framework, but not by myself. Can anyone tell me what the error message says.
It is about an extra module after all and a template file is missing. Is that correct so far? Can I just copy it in there myself?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_View_Exception: script '/.phtml' not found in path 

(/application/modules/default/views/scripts/) in 
/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:987 Stack trace: #0 
/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(883): Zend_View_Abstract->_script('/.phtml') 
#1 /library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(910): 
Zend_View_Abstract->render('/.phtml') #2 
library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(931): 
Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('/.phtml', NULL) #3 
library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(970): 
Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render() #4 
/libr in 
library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 335
```

Would be very grateful for any tip.

Greetz Bavra

Comment: It seems to me that this code is not based on ZF2 but on ZF1

Comment: For some reason the framework is looking for a view script without a name. Could you include the code where this error happens?